# Compile as release in visual studio using command line

Tags: visual-studio, compilation

I am using visual studio 2013 to compile c++ code on the command line (cl.exe). I understand that when using the ide, there is an option to compile in release mode or debug mode.

Does this option exist for the command line compiler as well? How can it be accessed?

I have looked at all the options attached to cl.exe on the Microsoft website, but none seem to fit. Also the Microsoft website seems to only include inductions on how to compile for release via the ide.

Answer (score 4):

The tool you want to use is `MSBuild.exe`.

From a developer command prompt, run `msbuild /?` for all the options.

Examples:

```
MSBuild MyApp.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
MSBuild MyApp.csproj /t:Clean /p:Configuration=Debug;TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5
```

If you want to do this with cl.exe/link.exe, there is a big "it depends" on what switches you want.  If you are after the pure defaults, it still might depend on how your project might look in Visual Studio.  An easy way to do this is to create a simple project in VS, look at project properties for `Configuration Properties` and see the `Command Line` for each.  Or go through help with `cl /?` and `link /?`

For a basic project that might be:

Release:

```
/GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\ConsoleApplication2.pch"
```

Debug:

```
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\ConsoleApplication2.pch"
```

As you can see, there are many options, no single answer, however the big differentiation for `Release` builds is `/D "NDEBUG"` and `/O2`

Comment: it seems that `msbuild` is for projects. I have been compiling the source code `cl main.cpp` (pretty much the same way I would compile things with g++ on a linux distro). Do I need to turn my code into a project in order to get the "release" build?

Comment: Added some info for cl.exe.

Comment: I tried compiling via the RELEASE mode, however, I was able to debug my code. Any way to strip the debug symbol from the binary?